# MySQL query not using best index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've got a table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
    `id` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `second_id` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `country` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `qty1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `qty2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `timestamp_second_id_country` (`timestamp`,`second_id`,`country`),
    KEY `timestamp_second_id` (`timestamp`,`second_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With has one row per `second_id`, per `timestamp`, per `country`.

I need a query that gets the quantities `qty1` and `qty2` for a certain `second_id` within a certain timeframe (ignoring the country), so something like:

```
SELECT timestamp, SUM(qty1) AS qty1, SUM(qty2) AS qty2
FROM order 
WHERE second_id = "<ID>" 
AND timestamp >= <min date>
AND timestamp < <max date>
GROUP BY timestamp 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Since the table contains about 12 million rows, this query takes ages (round 25 seconds), so I added the `timestamp_second_id` KEY to fix that, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to do it... Well, almost.

This is this query's EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                   | key                 | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | order | index | timestamp_second_id_country,timestamp_second_id | timestamp_second_id | 16      | NULL | 12185418 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

So it all looks good, it finds the 2 possible keys, uses the correct one, but it's still super slow... The funny part appears when I use `FORCE INDEX (timestamp_second_id)`, the EXPLAIN then becomes:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                   | key                 | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | order | range | timestamp_second_id_country,timestamp_second_id | timestamp_second_id | 16      | NULL | 3465998 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------+
```

So basically, it uses the same INDEX as before, but now the "Extra" uses an "index condition" and the query is quite fast (~1 sec).

So my question... Why isn't the query as fast without the FORCE INDEX as with it, even though looking at the EXPLAIN the same INDEX is being used? Is there any way to get this done without forcing the INDEX?

(Note that I also tried another queries, like an INNER query for grouping the timestamps, inside another query which selects the second_id and timestamp via a WHERE).

Comment: Are you using `country` in your `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes can only be used for searches up through the first range.

So, put your equality columns first, followed by one range column. Don't put any columns that aren't filtered on in the `WHERE` clause (actually, you can add additional columns for a covering index after the ones used in the filter, though they won't be used in the search).

So, given your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT timestamp, SUM(qty1) AS qty1, SUM(qty2) AS qty2
FROM order 
WHERE second_id = "<ID>" 
AND timestamp >= <min date>
AND timestamp < <max date>
GROUP BY timestamp 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Your index should be on the following columns, in order:

```
(second_id, timestamp)
```

Since the search condition on second_id is `=`, and timestamp is a "range".

For a covering index, it would be:

```
(second_id, timestamp, qty1, qty2)
```

Comment: worked perfectly, the query now takes ~0.03 seconds and the Explain's extra now says "Using index condition". Cheers!
I didn't try adding a covering index for columns qty1 and qty2 since in reality I have a lot of "qty" columns, so I guess adding an index for all doesn't make much sense. It works great without it anyway)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT timestamp, SUM(qty1) AS qty1, SUM(qty2) AS qty2
FROM order 
WHERE second_id = "<ID>" 
AND timestamp >= <min date>
AND timestamp < <max date>
GROUP BY timestamp 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

> KEY `covering_index` (`second_id`,`timestamp`,`qty1`,`qty2`)

Try with this INDEX combination. This is called covering index.

See Covering Index and Loose index scan for reference

Generally speaking if we have ranges inside our queries covering indexes are fast

http://www.arubin.org/blog/2010/11/18/loose-index-scan-vs-covered-indexes-in-mysql/